# Refile gem how to add a watermark on image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minimagick, refile

I have a rails 5.2.3 project, and I'm using the refile gem to upload files

How can I add a watermark from my file which is in my assets/images directory called logo.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rmagick to do that.

https://adityashedge.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/watermarking-images-with-imagemagick/